# Table not found error in SSAS

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssas

I am working on SSAS i developed an datacube and deployed succesfully but when i call that SSAS through my SSIS it says that some table is not found but the table exist in my SSAS module.
All things are working fine previous days suddenly this hapened kindly help me in this issue.

Comment: Are you running within Visual Studio or as a SQL Server Agent Job?

Comment: I am creating an Integration Service Regarding this

Comment: What are you trying to achieve through SSIS? processing tasks? Running MDX queries? If MDX, could you post the code you are using? Could you post the connection details you are using?

Comment: try changing `impersonation`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Internally the SSIS [Analysis Services Process task] uses the Id of the table and not the friendly name. This means that if you have redeployed the cube or pointed it at a different database then it will not find the table you have specified even though you know it is there. You would then need to update the package every time you recreated the SSAS object.

A more manageable solution would be to use the [Analysis services Execute DDL Task] task or use AMO inside of a script task.

*
You can get the XMLA command by clicking on the cube, dimension, measure group or partition in management studio, Select the Process option then chose the script option at the top. Paste this XMLA code into the command window in the task